# How do I count the lines of a Python output using Python script?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to make a function that always displays the current time on the first line of the terminal. So far I have a function to go up a specified number of lines:

```
LINE_UP = '\033[1A'
LINE_CLEAR = '\x1b[2K'
def upLines(string, lines):
    if lines != 0:
        for i in range(lines-1):
            print(LINE_UP)
    print(LINE_UP, end=LINE_CLEAR)
    print(string)
```

Along with a function that uses the datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime

def displayTime():
    while True:
        currentTime = datetime.now()
        a = datetime(currentTime.year, currentTime.month, currentTime.day, currentTime.hour, currentTime.minute, currentTime.second)
        upLines(a, 1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The issue with this is it will always only go up one line. I need to see the lines of PowerShell output, so I can call upLines() with the output length.

I've tried browsing the shutil module, but from what I can tell, .get_terminal_size() doesn't return the output size. I've also looked at similar questions, but they use PowerShell commands, rather than Python code. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: casually you may be interested in something like [blessings](https://pypi.org/project/blessings/)

Comment: I am using a windows, so blessings is not available.

Comment: Although I did find the blessed module, which is a fork for blessings, and that works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with the blessed module, using the blessed.Terminal.location(0, 0) command.